# Are cricket farms for human nutrition allowed in Germany?

Tags: food

Is it allowed to breed and sell *human edible* crickets commercially? Can't find any farms by googling.

Answer (score 3):

The exact answer will depend on the details (scale of the operation, where it is happening, what purpose the crickets are being sold for etc.), but in general:

**Yes, breeding and selling crickets is allowed in general.**

Here's an article (German) on someone who plans to breed insects for food (the article only says he is breeding "Heuschrecken", which could be several different species from the order *Orthoptera*, but it's probably close enough):

*[Insekten auf dem Teller - Thorsten Breitschuh baut eine Heuschreckenzucht auf](https://www.mz-web.de/koethen/insekten-auf-dem-teller-thorsten-breitschuh-baut-eine-heuschreckenzucht-auf-29942446)* ("Insects on the plate - Thorsten Breitschuh is starting an orthoptera breeding program")

The article does mention some legal problems, but they mostly revolve around getting the insects certified as safe food, and complying with environment regulations during the breeding.

Also, you can buy crickets and similar insects in many pet stores as animal food for reptiles, so breeding and selling them as animal food is definitely not prohibited.

Comment: I have to apologize @sleske for being unprecise - surely I have meant human food; nevertherless your answer provides helpful input. Thanks!